# How to reset autoincrement in phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

After deleting some rows I am trying to reset auto increment with these query

ALTER TABLE `test` AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT id FROM `test` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)

But it is not working. When I run seperately this query it works fine except SELECT part.
In brackets  It gives me all rows but without brackets it gives one row as I wanted in phpmyadmin.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem (https://xyproblem.info/). AUTO_INCREMENT should already be incrementing the value, why do you need to reset it manually?

Answer (score 1):

You go into the table on phpMyAdmin, you select operations at the top and then there is a setting for AUTO_INCREMENT which you can reset to 0 or any number you prefer.

Comment: Here it is in image format: https://i.ibb.co/g9Zz2Th/php-My-Admin.png

Comment: thank you for answering. I know to reset like this. I need as Sql query. I have autotask which doing dump my DB in after 2 weeks and it is deleting last 2 weeks records. That is why I need it

Comment: Ah okay sorry, so are you looking to reset it back to the last used number +1? ie if the last id was 16 so set it to 17?

Comment: auto_increment should be reset to last used number, not number + 1.

Comment: Yeah sorry you are right. I have been trying to do it on a dummy phpMyAdmin and I can't fathom it, I was able to do it with php in a separate file.

Comment: I need to do in php too. Didnt check if it works. Did work for you?

Comment: Yes I was able to do it in PHP setting a variable for the last entry `SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` then use another SQL query to set the AUTO_INCREMENT to the variable. If you need an example please let me know but it seems you have a good knowledge of how it all works.

Comment: Thank you for help. I am trying to do it with one query. If I can I'll share it